# check if an email in my database while sign up, using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, dao

I am programming an IHM for sign up the users, I need to check if this user is already in database(mysql), checking by his email . can you help me please.
I can save my user now but how to check if this user by his email

this is my Dao layer class :

```
public class UserDaoMysql implements UserDao {

    private Session session;


    private void openSession(){
        SessionFactory sessionFactory=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
    }

    private void closeSession(){
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }

    public void insert(User user) {

        if(checkEmail(user)){

        openSession();
        User p = new User(user.getName(), user.getEmail(), user.getPassword());
        session.save(p);
        System.out.println("sauvegarde reussi");
        closeSession();

        }



    }

    public boolean checkEmail(User user){


        return true;
    }

}
```

this is my user bean :

```
@ManagedBean(name="user")
public class User {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String confirmationPass;
//  private image 


    public User() {
        super();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


    public String getConfirmationPass() {
        return confirmationPass;
    }

    public void setConfirmationPass(String confirmationPass) {
        this.confirmationPass = confirmationPass;
    }


    public User(int id, String name, String email, String password,
            String confirmationPass) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.confirmationPass = confirmationPass;
    }

    public User(int id, String name, String email, String password) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public User(String name, String email, String password) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", Name=" + name + ", email=" + email
                + ", password=" + password + "]";
    }

    public void save(){


        UserBusiness userBusiness = new UserBusinessImp();
        userBusiness.add(new User(name, email,password));

    }

}
```

And I have a table user in my database.

thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would use NamedQuery for this. Define named query in your `User` entity like this:

```
...
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByEmail", 
query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.email = :email")})
@ManagedBean(name="user")
public class User {
...
```

And then add method like this to your DAO

```
public List<User> getUsersByEmail(String email){
    openSession();
    Session session;
    Query query = session.getNamedQuery("User.findByEmail");
    query.setString("email", email);
    Lis<Users> users = query.list();
    closeSession();
    return users;
}
```

This method is little bit more generic you can make it more specific returning `user` count only.

Comment: Why do you use `like` if you're not using any wildcard?

Comment: Your right it would be probably better to use `=` (exact match) in this case. I will edit my answer.